# How to deploy Axis2.war in Jboss-7

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jboss7.x, web-deployment

Hi every one I am new in jboss-7 i deploy axis2.war in jboss-7
folder structure is `jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments`
I have put axis2.war in side the folder deployment.

Here is my log file:

```
 =========================================================================

16:04:18,897 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
16:04:20,402 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
16:04:20,590 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" starting
16:04:28,285 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
16:04:28,285 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
16:04:28,382 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
16:04:28,441 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
16:04:28,561 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
16:04:28,706 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
16:04:28,710 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:04:28,722 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
16:04:28,730 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
16:04:28,737 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
16:04:28,766 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
16:04:29,656 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.7.Final)
16:04:30,862 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
16:04:30,904 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
16:04:31,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
16:04:31,533 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.1.GA
16:04:32,365 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
16:04:33,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/vivekray/Desktop/jboss-as-7.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments
16:04:33,304 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found axis2.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called axis2.war.dodeploy
16:04:33,314 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999
16:04:33,316 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
16:04:34,048 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:04:34,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started in 17065ms - Started 134 of 205 services (70 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Axis2.war is deployed successfully, but if I request the URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/axis2`

I am getting this error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /axis2
type Status report
message /axis2
description The requested resource (/axis2) is not available.
```

My question is: Is this URL wrong or am I doing some mistake during deployment time.
Please suggest some advice to me.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

> Axis2.war is deployed successfully

No.

It just says:

> To trigger deployment create a file called axis2.war.dodeploy